# I'm getting null characters at the end of string

Tags: c#

i'm reading RFID tag using the API and when i try to send the read data to web by making a get request i'm getting `12233445556\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000`.

how do i remove the`\u0000` from the string after reading so that i can only pass `12233445556`?

i'm using `NRfidApi`

```
ReadMemBankData = new string(new char[512]);|
rfid.OperationTime = (uint)0;

RFID_RESULT result = rfid.ReadMemBank(isSyncMode, MemBank, nWordPtr, nWordCount, false, AccessPassword, ReadMemBankData);
```

i'm passing ReadMemBankData as a parameter while doing GET.

Comment: Which API are you using? What is your code? We need more information in order to give you a good answer

Comment: i have updated the question with the code for your ref.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string s = ...;
s = s.TrimEnd('\0');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:
  `yourString.TrimEnd('\u0000');`

Answer (score 2):

you need to replace the null characters first then trim them.

```
string val = "12233445556\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000";
val  = val.Replace("\u0000", String.Empty).Trim();
```

Or

```
val  = val.Replace("\0", String.Empty).Trim();
```

The replace function replaces the null characters with empty string, the trim removes any leading or trailing white spaces;

Answer (score 0):

```
        Regex.Replace(yourString, @"(\\u0000)+$", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace null characters with empty string.

```
var str = "stringwithnullcharacters";
var str1 = str.Replace("\0", string.Empy);
```